# Java Thread monitoring. How to find out non daemon live threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, visualvm, jconsole, jstack

I see in JConsole that I still have 2 non daemon threads but I can't find out which exactly (total number of thread is beyond 30).
Visual VM doesn't provide such information.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Run:

```
$ jstack PID | grep tid= | grep -v daemon
```

This will dump all the thread of a given Java PID, filter lines with thread names and filter out non-daemon ones.

Remove `-v` to print daemon threads only.

Comment: unfortunately leaves a few odd threads in there, like GC threads, but close enough! :)

Comment: A tip for future readers: you can find jstack in your JDK's bin folder

Answer (score 2):

Take a thread dump in VisualVM. Daemon threads have the word '`daemon`' next to the thread name.

```
"Default RequestProcessor" daemon prio=1 tid=101e58000 nid=0x124d86000 runnable [124d85000]
```

Comment: i dont see this in visualvm 1.33 on linux. which window do you refer to?